# Explaining cardinality of set of all functions domain and codomain

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have the below question that is being asked of me. For both parts, it is my understanding that a set has a specific cardinality of A -> B if it is a bijection of A -> B.

From the question I think what `(a)` is asking is for the cardinality of all possible functions that map parts of A to B, which I don't think leverages the bijection. How would I go about identifying ALL of the functions withougt brute forcing every possible combination?

And for `(b)`, since a bijection implies that it is `one-to-one` AND `onto` then would would the cardinality be `0`?

[image]

Comment: You could try thinking of a function $f$ as set of ordered pairs $(x, f(x))$. Or, for each point in the domain, think of "choosing" a point in the codomain to pair it with. Then use basic combinatorics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first paragraph makes no sense: $A\to B$ is not a notation that represents a cardinality. What *is* true is that sets $A$ and $B$ have the *same* cardinality if and only if there is a bijection from one to the other. And neither (a) nor (b) asks about the cardinalities of the sets $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{a,b,c\}$.

For (a) you are supposed to calculate how many functions there are from $A$ to $B$. A function from $A$ to $B$ is a set of two ordered pairs of the form $\{\langle 1,x\rangle,\langle 2,y\rangle\}$, where $x$ and $y$ are elements of $B$, possibly the same. For example, $f=\{\langle 1,c\rangle,\langle 2,a\rangle\}$ and $g=\{\langle 1,b\rangle,\langle 2,b\rangle\}$ are functions with domain $A$ and codomain $B$ (i.e., functions from $A$ to $B$): in more familiar notation, $f$ is the function such that $f(1)=c$ and $f(2)=a$, and $g$ is the constant function $g(1)=g(2)=b$. Counting these functions is straightforward. When you build one of them, $\{\langle 1,x\rangle,\langle 2,y\rangle\}$, how many different choices are there for $x$? How many for $y$? In how many ways can you combine these choices to get different functions?

For (b) you are to count the one-to-one functions from $A$ to $B$. In other words, you need to exclude from your count the ones like $g$ above that are not one-to-one. Now when you construct one, say $\{\langle 1,x\rangle,\langle 2,y\rangle\}$, you want $x$ and $y$ to be *different* members of $B$. Say you choose $x$ first and then $y$. How many choices are there for $x$? How many for $y$ *once* $x$ *has been chosen*? And how many different combinations can you get altogether?

Note that nowhere in these questions is there any mention of functions from $A$ ***onto*** $B$. There are in fact no such functions, but that fact has no bearing on the problems.